# how can i cause a segmentation fault on this program? (to help me find a buffer overflow exploit)

Tags: c, memcpy, buffer-overflow

I see that the code below uses memcpy which i can use to exploit this program and cause a buffer overflow, but i cant seem to make it crash. No matter what character argument i pass to it i just get "error opening packet file." Any ideas how?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define MAX_ADDR_LEN 128

#define ADDR_LENGTH_OFFSET 4
#define ADDR_OFFSET 8

typedef unsigned char shsize_t;

typedef struct{
  char addr[MAX_ADDR_LEN];
  shsize_t len;
} arp_addr;

void
print_address(char *packet)
{
  arp_addr hwaddr;
  int i;

  hwaddr.len = (shsize_t) *(packet + ADDR_LENGTH_OFFSET);
  memcpy(hwaddr.addr, packet + ADDR_OFFSET, hwaddr.len);

  printf("Sender hardware address: ");
  for (i = 0; i < hwaddr.len - 1; i ++)
    printf("%02hhx::", hwaddr.addr[i]);
  printf("%02hhx\n", hwaddr.addr[hwaddr.len - 1]);  

  return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct stat sbuf;
  char *packet;
  int fd;

  if (argc != 2){
    printf("Usage: %s <packet file>\n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if ((stat(argv[1], &sbuf)) < 0){
    printf("Error opening packet file\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0){
    printf("Error opening packet file\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if ((packet = (char *)malloc(sbuf.st_size * sizeof(char))) == NULL){
    printf("Error allocating memory\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (read(fd, packet, sbuf.st_size) < 0){
    printf("Error reading packet from file\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  close(fd);
  print_address(packet);
  free(packet);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I just don't feel comfortable helping people out with malicious code, even it if is "homework".

Comment: There is no notion of "crash" in C, and thus no programmatic way to cause a crash.

Comment: fair enough @DOK, it is for a computer security class. Kerrek SB i should say segmentation fault.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but I don't think you can solve this assignment if you are not able to notice that the first argument is a file not a random character.

Comment: @jfisk: Likewise, a segmentation fault is not a notion in C. Rather, it is something that your operating system's memory manager deals with, and it will send a signal to your application if that happens. Basically, you cannot control uncontrollable behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

When you do something like write past the end of a buffer there is no guarantee that the program will crash.  This is called undefined behavior, which literally means that you can make no reasonable assumptions as to what will happen.

The program itself appears relatively well behaved.  As long as `len` is calculated properly I don't see any way for you to cause an overrun via input.  Just because a program uses `memcpy` doesn't mean that it is vulnerable to attack.  The only attack vector I see is if you pass it a carefully crafted file such that the length is calculated incorrectly:

```
hwaddr.len = (shsize_t) *(packet + ADDR_LENGTH_OFFSET)
```

In this line the program reads `ADDR_LENGTH_OFFSET` bytes from the address of `packet` to get the data length.  Obviously that is problematic if you craft a file with an erroneous value for the data length in the header (i.e., a data length > `MAX_ADDR_LEN`).

BTW, the argument is a file, not a character.  You won't be able to do anything passing it nonsense input because `read` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

> No matter what character argument i pass to it i just get "error
>   opening packet file."

You need to pass a valid file name as an argument, not random characters.

As others have indicated, the memcpy() isn't the security problem. The problem is that the length parameter passed to memcpy() comes from user input (the file you specified). If you specify a file that has a length field of, say, a billion, you will probably see a crash (and, yes, 'crash' is accepted vernacular).

Answer (score 0):

Since there is rather limited checking on the size of the packet, you can pass it the name of an empty or very short file and the `print_address()` code will mess around out of bounds.

Also, since the code reads a length from the data read from the file, you can place an arbitrary number at relevant position and make the code go running around most places in memory.